# Grails 3.0.7 GSP auto reloading in Production mode

Tags: grails, gsp, reloading

I have a Grails 3.0.7 war file that i am deploying on a Tomcat. I have a few GSP views that i would like the users to change the font/css etc (similar to changing html in a deployed web application). I am using Bootstrap as well in the views and hence the increased need to allow CSS/fonts modifications at runtime.

Question is, how do i allow the users to change the CSS as they deem necessary, without having to recompile the code for every change? I have tried grails.gsp.enable.reload as true without setting the grails.gsp.view.dir (as its all under Tomcat) but that does not help.

Comment: I should add that we share the war file across our client base and let the clients change display elements (logos, branding, font color/sizes etc.). So the changes would only be strictly from a display perspective.

Comment: The reload stuff I think is only for development mode. When building a war file assets goes through minify and uglifyjs process by default. You can try disabling all that. But still unsure if you be able to write to assets style sheet folder in production since as a war it is not really that formal structure we are so used to in grails. It may have to be some hackish other way whereby those pages load $username template on that template maybe you have a raw him style sheet tag that loads in their values. I guess that is the easiest way